# How do I configure nginx.conf proxy to work with S3 and AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, nginx-reverse-proxy, aws-fargate

I have a number of UIs (Angular) that are currently deployed on ECS Fargate. These apps are built using a base nginx image, and further configurations are set in the nginx.conf file, etc. All of these apps also filter through an AWS ALB and have route paths set for them. Currently, each of these apps are using *separate* nginx containers and they are working fine.

However, I am wanting to serve these up using *one* nginx container as a proxy that pulls the UI files from S3, but still uses the ALB to route the requests.

At this point, I have just been trying to get one sample Angular app working. I've build the dist file using ng build and loaded the artifacts in s3. After updating the nginx configurations, I am able to load the index.html in the browser, but for the css and js files its either not finding the files or not loading them for some reason (see png below). I have a default route set on the ALB that returns a text message when no artifacts are found on the path so that looks like what is being returned.

[image]

I've tried various things to get this to work and have not found a solution. The following are the basic setup files im using for this. I'm needing insight from someone who knows nginx better than me to get a path forward.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.16.1-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN cp -r /usr/share/nginx/html /etc/nginx/html
RUN chown nginx:nginx /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i -e 's/<bucketnamepassedinhere>/${S3BUCKET}/;' \
    -i -e 's/<hostnamepassedhere>/${HOSTNAME}/;' \
    -i -e 's/8.8.8.8/{DNS}/;' \

chown nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

exec "$@"
```

**nginx.conf**

```
daemon off;
user nginx;

worker_processes 4;

events { 
    worker_connections 1024; 
}

http {
        log_format logstash_json escape=json '{'
        '"agent": "$http_user_agent", '
        '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent", '
        '"bytes_sent": "$bytes_sent", '
        '"clientip": "$remote_addr", '
        '"http_host": "$http_host", '
        '"log_timestamp": "$time_local", '
        '"proxy_host": "$proxy_host", '
        '"referrer": "$http_referer", '
        '"request": "$request", '
        '"request_time": $request_time, '
        '"request_length": $request_length, '
        '"status": $status, '
        '"upstream_addr": "$upstream_addr", '
        '"upstream_response_time": "$upstream_response_time", '
        '"upstream_status": "$upstream_status", '
        '"x_forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for", '
        '"x_forwarded_port": "$http_x_forwarded_port", '
        '"x_forwarded_proto": "$http_x_forwarded_proto"'
        '}';

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log logstash_json;

        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_types application/json application/x-tar;
        gzip_min_length 1000;

        variables_hash_max_size 1024;
        variables_hash_bucket_size 64;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        types_hash_bucket_size 64;
        client_max_body_size 100m;

        proxy_read_timeout 60;
        proxy_buffers 256 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;

        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        # default_type application/octet-stream;
        include mime.types;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <servername>.com;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=30s;
        index index.html;
        gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/x-javascript text/css application/json text/javascript;

        location = /app/ {
            set $S3BUCKET "<bucketnamepassedinhere>.s3.amazonaws.com";
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            proxy_buffering        off;
            proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs;
            proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
            proxy_set_header       Host $S3BUCKET;
            proxy_set_header       Connection "";
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_pass https://$S3BUCKET/index.html;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: If I use just `location /app` instead of `location = /app` the the health checks fails and after some testing this appears to be because of the route path set in the ALB. Im finding they need to to be identical on each, but I could be wrong.

Again Im able to reach the index.html, just not load the css and js for some reason. All of the dist files in the bucket are in the same location (i.e., there are no separate folders). Any insight as to what Im missing?

Comment: So I got it working but I had to set the base ALB path to default to the target group and not go through another route path. Ideally what I would want to do is be able to set the ALB path to /app and then the url would be https://domainname.come/app and then automatically hit the index.html. I know if I have to have base route paths setup, though. Any idea on what that nginx config would look like so that with the location and any rewrites or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just submitted this PR, I'm hoping it might help with your issue.

https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway/pull/158

It allows you to specify a portion of the path the request to be removed.  For example, let's say you have an ALB rule that sends traffic from **[www.mysite.com/mybucket](http://www.mysite.com/mybucket)** to the S3 gateway, which is connected to the bucket **s3://mybucket**.  If you request **[www.mysite.com/mybucket/myfile.txt](http://www.mysite.com/mybucket/myfile.txt)**, the request would normally fail as it would try to pull the file from **s3://mybucket/mybucket/myfile.txt**.

With this change, setting the new env var to

```
STRIP_LEADING_DIRECTORY_PATH=/mybucket
```

will instead try to pull the file from **s3://mybucket/myfile.txt**.